# ckeditor language get wrong 'user language'

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

AS the API doc above says, if lanaguage is empty , ckeditor would show language that default language has. But my application show english.

My code :

```
 CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar': 'Custom',
    'toolbar_Custom': [
      [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike' ],
      [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-',  'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
      [ 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley'],
      [  'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ],
      [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ],
    ],
    'width' : '100%',
    'defaultLanguage' : 'ko',
    'language' : '',
}
```

}

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django-CKEDITOR actually overrides this flag by using the settings.py's language settings. You need to make sure all the following settings are enabled:

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('ko', _('Korean')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]

USE_I18N = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
   ...
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It helps solving my problem. For the other people who have stuck on the same trouble, this code have to add 

'from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _ '

this . Then, it will completely work!